# Accelerated C++: Can I substitute raw pointers for smart pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, smart-pointers

I love this book, sadly it does not cover smart pointers as they were not part of the standard back then. So when reading the book can I fairly substitute every mentioned pointer by a smart pointer, respectively reference?

Comment: Do you have a specific example of a program from the book that would benefit from using a smart pointer?  Pointers aren't introduced until over halfway through the book and most of the programs that use pointers are there to explain how to manage them yourself, namely through the implementation of the `Vec` class (which effectively introduces the rule of three) and through the discussion of handle classes (a handle class for a dynamically allocated resource is basically a smart pointer).  I'm curious where you think a smart pointer would be beneficial (I haven't read the book recently.)

Comment: @james-mcnellis I agree, I haven't read the book so far, this was a preventive question.

Comment: Ok; I wouldn't worry about smart pointers while reading the book then.  Once you've read the book, it should be pretty easy to understand all of the Boost smart pointers and how they work and when they should be used:  _Accelerated C++_ provides a very thorough explanation of handle classes that should help you to understand correct lifetime management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are different kinds of smart pointers. For example:

You could create a `scoped_ptr` class, which would be useful when you're allocating for a task within a block of code, and you want the resource to be freed automatically when it runs of of scope.

Something like:

```
template <typename T>
class scoped_ptr
{
 public:
    scoped_ptr(T* p = 0) : mPtr(p) {}
    ~scoped_ptr() { delete mPtr; }
 //...
};
```

Additionally you could create a `shared_ptr` who acts the same but keeps a ref count. Once the ref count reach 0 you deallocate.

`shared_ptr` would be useful for pointers stored in STL containers and the like.

So yes, you could use smart pointers for most of the purposes of your program. 
But think judiciously about what kind of smart pointer you need and why.

Do not simply "find and replace" all the pointers you come across.

Comment: Also, while creating your own smart pointer is easy, coming up with one that has no bugs is surprisingly hard. In the last twenty years, every project I worked on where they had their own smart pointers, sooner or later nasty bugs were found.

Comment: sbi: Duh. It was for demonstration purposes only. Of course it lacks, hence the //...

Comment: (You need to properly @address comment replies, or we won't see them on our Responses tab. I only found this one by accident.) Yeah, but it lacks in a position that's _very_ vital when designing and implementing a smart pointer.

Comment: @sbi: That was no implementation. That was only to illustrate the scoped mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

"Smart Pointer" is a bit of a misnomer.  The "smart" part is that they will do some things for you, whether or not you need, want, or even understand what those things are.  And that's really important.  Because sometimes you'll want to go to the store, and smart pointers will [drive you to church](http://www.nuk3.com/jokes/648/If-Operating-Systems-Drove-Your-Car.html).  Smart pointers solve some very specific problems.  Many would argue that if you think you need smart pointers, then [you're probably solving the wrong problem](http://solid-angle.blogspot.com/2010/02/musings-on-data-oriented-design.html).  I personally try not to take sides.  Instead, I use a toolbox metaphor - you need to really understand the problem you're solving, and the tools that you have at your disposal.  Only then can you remotely expect to select the right tool for the job.  Best of luck, and keep questioning!

Answer (score 2):

No.

Pointers which represent object ownership should be replaced by smart pointers.

Other pointers should be replaced by iterators (which in the simplest case is just a `typedef` for a raw pointer, but no one would think they need to delete).

And of course, the implementation code for smart pointers and iterators will continue to need raw pointers.